# Ubuntu 20.04 logind.service not found

Tags: services, systemd-logind

/etc/systemd/logind.conf is being ignored.  I tracked it down to the fact that logind.service is not running.  When I:

systemctl start logind.service

The response is:

Failed to start logind.service: Unit logind.service not found

No other problems with the system noted.

System is a Dell Latitude e3550 with Ubuntu 20.04 as the only operating system ever installed since replacing the disk with a 1TB SSD.

Comment: Isn't the name *systemd*-logind.service?

Comment: Never saw that name in a dozen or so lid switch problem threads.  Checked for that name just now.  Not found

Comment: Found it.  I will post my lid switch issue under an appropriate question heading.  Thanks.